# Use BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner and post-processing code for Dataflow template

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'd like to run some code after my pipeline finishes all processing, so I'm using `BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner` and placing code after `pipeline.run()` in `main`.

This works properly when I run the job from the command line using `BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner`. The code under `pipeline.run()` runs after the pipeline has finished processing.

However, it does not work when I try to run the job as a template. I deployed the job as a template (with `TemplatingDataflowPipelineRunner`), and then tried to run the template in a Cloud Function like this:

```
dataflow.projects.templates.create({
    projectId: 'PROJECT ID HERE',
    resource: {
        parameters: {
            runner: 'BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner'
        },
        jobName: `JOB NAME HERE`,
        gcsPath: 'GCS TEMPLATE PATH HERE'
    }
}, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        // etc
    }
    callback();
});
```

The runner does not seem to take. I can put gibberish under runner and the job still runs.

The code I had under `pipeline.run()` does not run when each job runs -- it runs only when I deploy the template.

Is it expected that the code under `pipeline.run()` in `main` would not run each time the job runs? Is there a solution for executing code after the pipeline is finished?

(For context, the code after `pipeline.run()` moves a file from one Cloud Storage bucket to another. It's archiving the file that was just processed by the job.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this expected behavior. A template represents the pipeline itself, and allows (re-)executing the pipeline by launching the template. Since the template doesn't include any of the code from the `main()` method, it doesn't allow doing anything after the pipeline execution.

Similarly, the `dataflow.projects.templates.create` API is just the API to launch the template.

The way the blocking runner accomplished this was to get the job ID from the created pipeline and periodically poll to observe when it has completed. For your use case, you'll need to do the same:

1. Execute `dataflow.projects.templates.create(...)` to create the Dataflow job. This should return the job ID.
2. Periodically (every 5-10s, for instance) poll `dataflow.projects.jobs.get(...)` to retrieve the job with the given ID, and check what state it is in.

Comment: While the answer is correct, it would be an awesome feature to have run a blocking pipeline from a template!